# How do I handle error checking based only on Items displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Greetings again helpers,

I have these snips:

```
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function validate() {
missinginfo = "";
if (document.form.catdescription.value == "0") {
missinginfo += "\n     -  Category CANNOT be blank";
}
if (document.form.pcode.value == "")  {
missinginfo += "\n     -  Product Code CANNOT be blank";
}
if (document.form.pname.value == "") {
missinginfo += "\n     -  Product Name CANNOT be blank";
}
if (document.form.pdescription.value == "") {
missinginfo += "\n     -  Product Description CANNOT be blank";
}
if (( form.IsSpecial[0].checked == false ) && ( form.IsSpecial[1].checked == false )) {
missinginfo += "\n     -  please check Yes or No";
}
if ((document.form.pphoto.value == "") || (document.form.pphoto.value == "NA"))
 {
missinginfo += "\n     -  Photo is either blank or does not contain NA";
}
if (document.form.unitprice.value == "") {
missinginfo += "\n     -  Price is NOT blank";
}
if (document.form.file2.value == "") {
missinginfo += "\n     -  Browse a picture to upload";
}

if (missinginfo != "") {
missinginfo ="_____________________________\n" +
"Please ensure that:\n" +
missinginfo + "\n_____________________________" +
"\nPlease re-enter and submit again!";
alert(missinginfo);
return false;
}
else return true;
}
//  End -->
</script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function ChangeDiv(id)
{
if(id == "No")
{
document.getElementById('nof').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('yesf').style.display = "none";
}
else
{
document.getElementById('nof').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('yesf').style.display = "block";
}
}
//  End -->
</script>
</head>
   <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=4 BORDERCOLOR="YELLOW" >
    <tr>
    <td class="body1" div align="right">
       <div id="yesf" style="display:none;">
       Promo Start Date:
      <input type="text" name="pstartdate" class="normaltxt"><br>
       Promo End Date:
      <input type="text" name="penddate" class="normaltxt"><br>
       PROMO Price:
      <input type="text" name="txtsprice" value="">
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="body1" div align="right">
     <div id="nof">
      Regular Price:
      <input type="text" name="unitprice" value="">
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

These are relevant code.

If the user clicks on the Yes radio button, all form fields inside the -->  are displayed. If the user checks the No radio button the only form field called price is displayed for data entry.

So far so good. The issue I am struggling with is how to make sure the Javascript validation code I posted above only raises an alert for only visible form fields.

Comment: Try the `:visible` selector, and start use jQuery selectors or at least `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say it but, that code is nasty!

Replace those kind of lines:

```
if (document.form.catdescription.value == "0") {...
```

With:

```
if ($('#catdescription').val() == "0") {...
```

Then you can check validate it only if it's visible easly with the `:visible` selector:

```
if ($('#catdescription:visible').val() == "0"){
    missinginfo += "\n     -  Category CANNOT be blank";
}
```

Comment: Hi Gdoron, is the code jquery? I am using regular javascript. If jquery, do you have complete code?

Comment: @Kenny. Yes this is `jQuery`... I can't give you a "complete code" as it impossible to know exactly what you're trying to do and when. Just use those snippet, and learn [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: ok, can you please pass along some good links that will guide me? I have not found anything meaningful yet. I did state clearly what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Kenny. My answer shows how to select elements by their id(`$(#elementId)`), and how to select them only if they are visible(`$(#elementId:visible)`) and how to get their value(`$(#elementId:visible).val()`), what do you need more?!

Comment: thanks gdoron. In javascript, you start with something like this: SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> <!-- Begin function validate() { .  How do I start jquery before using the selectors you provided?

Comment: @Kenny. It's just like every other javascript code, you just need to reference the jQuery library with: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Array 1 will contain the IDs of the fields which will be displayed for "Yes",
Array 2 will be the same , just for the fields which will displayed for "No".

After setting it up , use a condition that will check which radio button was selected
"Yes" Or "No" , and as result of this condition you will check the fields of the matching
array.

If "yes" is selected then: for each element in Array1 , have a `document.getElementById(elem)` and validate it.

Need some code or you got the idea?